# Query database to send SMS

Tags: flask, twilio, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a simple SMS app using Flask, Twilio, and SqlAlchemy. When someone texts my Twilio number, it populates the database, but I can't  query the Postgres database to populate the "to" field. Here's the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import twilio.twiml
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://localhost/twilio_sms'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
account_sid = ""
auth_token = ""

# Database model
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, phone):
        self.phone = phone

# The script that processes the incoming phone numbers
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms():
    phone = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone = request.values.get('From')
        if not db.session.query(User).filter(User.phone == phone).count():
            reg = User(phone)
            db.session.add(reg)
            db.session.commit()
            resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
            with resp.message("Let's dance the night away!") as m:
                m.media("http://i.giphy.com/2lxG3ySjtbpBe.gif")
            return str(resp)

# Renders the form for message submission
@app.route("/form")
def form():
    return render_template('send.html')
```

Here's the section where I'm having trouble.

```
# The script that publishes the message
@app.route("/send", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send():
    phone = None
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    for users in db.session.query(User).filter(User.phone == phone):
        print users #Inserted to text whether the query returned any value
        #message = client.messages.create(to="users", from_="+twilio_number", body=request.form['Message'])
        #return render_template('success.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out... I had to convert the numbers into a list using `query` and then pass it as string.

```
@app.route("/send", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send():
    users = User.query.order_by(User.phone)
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    for user in users:
        message = client.messages.create(to=str(user), from_="+12125550433", body=request.form['Message'])
    return render_template('success.html')
```

Comment: Twilio employee here, I was too slow... was able to execute your code from github:  when I print users (User.query.order_by(User.phone)) here is the query:
SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.phone AS users_phone 
FROM users ORDER BY users.phone
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Aug/2015 11:39:00] "POST /send HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 0):

In your `send()` function you are assigning `phone = None` and then filtering your database query on that.

I believe you want to grab the number like you did above in `sms()` out of the request.

Comment: The `request.values.get('From')` comes from the initial text message and is then stored in a database. I'm new to SQLAlchemy and can't figure out how to query the phone numbers from the database and create a dictionary.

Comment: Since you're filtering on the users phone number in your database query, you'll have to figure out how to get that information inside your `/send` route. It's failing right now because you are telling it you want all the `User.phone` fields that ` == None`.

Comment: I published the full code on github: https://github.com/joshlsullivan/twilio-flask-sms